# Selenium Webdriver. Выбрать элеменет в iframe, который находится в другом iframe

Tags: python, selenium, python-2.x, selenium-webdriver

Не могу выбрать элемент, который находится в iframe, который в свою очередь находится в другом iframe. Нашел такой пример (у меня он не работает):

```
        iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
        driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
        div = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div')
        atr2 = div.get_attribute("id")
```

Answer (score 1):

Твой алгоритм должен быть таков

1. Найти внешний `iframe`. Запомнить его.
2. Переключится на этот `iframe`.
3. Далее искать внутрненний `iframe`. Запомнить его.
4. Переключиться на данный `iframe`.
5. Искать уже искомый элемент.

Не знаком с апи селениума для питона, но могу предположить, что ошибка в 4 строке - не выполнены пункты 3 и 4 из того, что я написал.

```
 iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
 driver.switch_to.default_content()
 driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
 iframe2 = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
 driver.switch_to.frame(iframe2);
 div = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div')
 atr2 = div.get_attribute("id")
```

Comment: я уже все голову сломал ;D

Comment: По поводу чего голову словал?

Comment: как это реализовать (

Comment: все легко и просто если явно указать названия   фреймов , но это не устойчиво (

Comment: Ну тогда ищи их по хпафу, например.